# Any map $\mathbb{CP}^4\to\mathbb{CP}^2\times\mathbb{CP}^2$ induces the trivial map on cohomology in all positive degrees.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to show the following:

> Any map $\mathbb{CP}^4\to\mathbb{CP}^2\times\mathbb{CP}^2$ induces the trivial map on cohomology in all positive degrees.

I can't peice together everything, though. Here are some things I know:

Let $f\colon \mathbb{CP}^4\to\mathbb{CP}^2\times\mathbb{CP}^2$ be a map. Note $H^\ast(\mathbb{CP}^2\times\mathbb{CP}^2;\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3)\otimes\mathbb{Z}[y]/(y^3)$ and $H^\ast(\mathbb{CP}^4;\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}[z]/(z^5)$ with $|x|=|y|=|z|=2$. We have an induced homomorphism $f^\ast\colon H^\ast(\mathbb{CP}^2\times\mathbb{CP}^2;\mathbb{Z})\to H^\ast(\mathbb{CP}^4;\mathbb{Z})$ with $f^\ast(x\otimes y)=z$.

Not sure what to do...

Comment: Note that under the isomorphism $H^\ast(\mathbb{CP}^2\times\mathbb{CP}^2;\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3)\otimes\mathbb{Z}[y]/(y^3)$, the element $x\otimes y$ has degree four, while $z$ has degree two, so your claim $f^*(x\otimes y) = z$ is incorrect. Instead, you can say that $f^*x = az$ and $f^*y = bz$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Right, thanks! I guess maybe then to use $f^\ast(x\smile y)=f^\ast(x)\smile f^\ast(y)=az\smile bz=abz^2$, but again stuck.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Albanese mentions in the comments, we have a homomorphism of graded rings $f^*\colon\mathbb Z[x]/x^3\otimes\mathbb Z[y]/y^3\to\mathbb Z[z]/z^5$. Thus, the elements $x\otimes1$ and $1\otimes y$, which have degree $2$, must be mapped to degree two elements in $\mathbb Z[z]/z^5$, namely $az$ and $bz$, respectively, for some integers $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.

Now, observe that $(az)^3=f^*(x)^3=f^*(x^3)=0$.

Comment: Where are we using that $f^\ast(x)=az$? Because $f^\ast(x)^3=0$ is always true, no? I am guessing at some point you'd want to say this implies $(az)^3=0$, and this cannot be as the order of $z$ is $5$. But then I don't see what we are contradicting...

Comment: $(az)^3=0$, so $a^3=0\in\mathbb Z$. Thus, $a=0$. Similarly, $(bz)^3=0$ so $b=0$. Thus $f^*$ is trivial on positive degrees.

Comment: I'm coming back to this question, but something here is confusing me - I don't see why $f^\ast\colon H^2(\mathbb{CP}^2\times\mathbb{CP}^2)\to H^2(\mathbb{CP}^4)$ is trivial. What does an arbitrary element of the domain look like if we let $x\in H^2(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ and $y\in H^2(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ be generators? By Kunneth I believe it should be $\times(x\otimes 1,1\otimes y)=(x\times1,1\times y)$, where $\times$ is the "cross-product map".

Comment: Yes, there is an isomorphism $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^2\times\mathbb{CP}^2)\simeq\mathbb Z[x]/x^3\otimes\mathbb Z[y]/y^3$. Under this isomorphism, $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^2\times\mathbb{CP}^2)$ corresponds to the degree $2$ elements, so is the free abelian group spanned by $\{x\otimes 1,1\otimes y\}$.